# updating an object property with linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections, hashcode

I have created an object and sadly for the life of me I couldn't figure out how to create a 3 property object with a hashed key (almost like a dictionary but instead of key and value, do key, value1 and value2)

As a work around I am using linq on a list of objects, which works fine but I want to know since linq is a querying language, can you update an object from it without creating a new object?

I want to essentially do this

```
    public void AddLineItemFulFilled(string itemID, int quantityOrdered, int quantityShipped)
 {
      if (!LineItems.Any(li => li.LineItemID.Equals(itemID)))
         LineItems.Add(new LineItemModel(lineItem, quantityOdered, quantityShipped));
      else
      {
          int matchingItem = 0;
          foreach(LineItemModel modUpdate in LineItems)
          {
              if(modUpdate.LineItemID.Equals(itemID) && matchingItem <= 1)
              {
                  modUpdate.QauntityShipped += quantityShipped;
                  matchingItem++;
              }
          }
      }
      else if(modUpdate.LineItemID.Equals(itemID))
         LineItems.RemoveAt(LineItems.InexOf(modUpdate));

 }
```

Will I get the same result with this?

```
 public void AddLineItemFulFilled(string itemID, int quantityOrdered, int quantityShipped)
            {
                if (!LineItems.Any(li => li.LineItemID.Equals(itemID)))
                    LineItems.Add(new LineItemModel(lineItem, quantityOdered, quantityShipped));
                else
                    LineItems.FirstOrDefault(li => li.LineItemID.Equals(itemID)).QauntityShipped += quantityShipped;
            }
```

Or will that make a second LineItemModel object with that ItemID?

(Alternatively is the hashed object I want to make easier than I realize? The object has 3 attributes, an ItemID string used as a de facto key, an int value of quantityShipped, essentially value1, and an int value of quantityOrdered, essentially value2)?

Comment: Are you wanting `quantityShipped` and `quantityOrdered` to participate in the uniqueness for the key, or do you want strictly `ItemID` to be the key?

Comment: just itemID, the quantityShipped is for a report later and the quantityOrdered is to compare with quantityShipped to only mark an item shipped if the item is fully shipped, so they don't need to be unique or part of any combined key, just tied to the item ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not do something as simple as this:

```
public class MyObject {
    public int ItemID { get; set;}
    public int QuantityShipped { get; set;}
    public int QuantityOrdered { get; set;}
}

public Dictionary<int, MyObject> myDictionary;
public string Foo(int itemId) {
    var value = myDictionary[itemId];
    return string.Format("Quantity ordered = {0}, quantity shipped = {1}", value.QuantityShipped, value.QuantityOrdered);
}
```

Comment: FYI, You can also use Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>> but it would be less readable

Comment: just basically have my entire object as the value of a dictionary with the key matching the itemID of my object? That ill probably work actually. I'm going to mark this resolved as that's a much simpler solution for me but I'll leave the question named as it is in case someone has a similar question about linq and someone can answer if the item is editied in teh original list or cloned in the second code snippet. Thank you!

Comment: There's no update on the QuantityShipped-property in this solution so probably I might have got the question wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

First. There's a typo at `Q(au)ntityShipped`.

Second: The second approach is okay but try to avoid repeating the same lambdas because even if the syntax looks short, each one is (potentially) a loop through the whole list of objects.

I'd go for this:

```
public void AddLineItemFulFilled(string itemID, int quantityOrdered, int quantityShipped)
{
    var li = LineItems.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LineItemID.Equals(itemID));

    if (li == null)
      LineItems.Add(new LineItemModel(lineItem, quantityOdered, quantityShipped));
    else
        li.QuantityShipped += quantityShipped;
}
```

And no, `FirstOrDefault` wont return a second object or anything like that. If it finds the matching object you will get a pointer to that one. Changing properties on that given object will do exactly what you want.

Comment: wasnt that the solution for you?

Comment: yes bu Tim also gave me a solution with a different approach and I don't think it lets m mark both. It won't even let me upvote your answer yet